# PHP Regex, every Check got true

Tags: php, regex

I've got some problems with my Regex in PHP

Code:

```
$pregResult = preg_match('/(([S][S])[1-9]{2})|(([W][S])[1-9]{2}\/[1-9]{2})/', $newModul->getGueltigkeitszeitraum());
```

I've got every time 1 as result ... (true)

What I want to do is only to allow following combinations

```
SS00 - SS99
WS00/00 - WS99/99
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You want to allow the `SS00` and `WS00/00`?

Comment: is that the hyphen actually present in your input string?

Comment: can anyone explane me why this question is downwoated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
$pregResult = preg_match('~^(?:(SS[0-9]{2})(?:\h+-\h+(?1))|(WS[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})(?:\h+-\h+(?2)))$~m', $newModul->getGueltigkeitszeitraum());
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hK1uH1/1)

`(?1)` recurses the 1st subpattern.

`[0-9]` Matches all the digits from 0 to 9.

**OR**

`SS00 - SS99`, i think you mean from `SS00` to `SS99` . In that case, you could use `\d` (matches a digit which ranges from 0 to 9).

```
$pregResult = preg_match('~^(?:SS\d{2}|WS\d{2}\/\d{2})$~m', $newModul->getGueltigkeitszeitraum());
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hK1uH1/2)

Comment: @Felix i don't know how thw accepted answer matches `SS00` , since he used `[1-9]`

Comment: Yes I've seen this just in time and corrected it :) but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$pregResult = preg_match('/^([S][S][0-9]{2}|[W][S][0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}|Schuljahr[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})$/',
     $newModul->getGueltigkeitszeitraum());
```

`^`: the pattern should be at the beginning of the string

`$`: nothing should be after the pattern in the string

`[S]`: the character S

`[0-9]`: a digit (same as `\d`)

`[0-9]{2}`: exact 2 digits

Look here for more information [PHP Regular Expression](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider adding a bit more hints, what the was wrong in the first place.

Comment: I don't really understand that synthax ... its different from normal regex :( ... I also need to check Schuljahr00/01 to Schuljahr99/00

I've tried this ... but dosn't work
`$pregResult = preg_match('/^(Schuljahr)$^(\d{2}\/\d{2})$/', $newModul->getGueltigkeitszeitraum());`

Comment: You have a `$^` after Schuljahr. With that you say the input string should end after Schuljahr and begin with the stuff after `$^`. This makes no sense at all. btw. I edited my answer and included this :D